# Get static data & selected data from table only for changed rows

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, html-select

I am trying to do multiple things at once & can't seem to get everything to work together. I have a table full of select boxes that dynamically populates from a php foreach loop. The user makes changes & on a button click, I am trying to iterate through the table & grab **only** the rows that have been changed & get the **selected** data values. Here is what my table looks like:

```
<table id="myTable>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>ColumnHeader1</th>
     <th>ColumnHeader2</th>
     <th>ColumnHeader3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td name="columnOneData">123456</td>
      <td name="columnTwoData">
         <select>
            <option value="1">Data1</option>
            <option value="2">Data2</option>
            <option value="3">Data3</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td name="columnThreeData>
         <select>
            <option value="1">Data1</option>
            <option value="2">Data2</option>
            <option value="3">Data3</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td name="columnOneData">987654</td>
      <td name="columnTwoData">
         <select>
            <option value="1">Data1</option>
            <option value="2">Data2</option>
            <option value="3">Data3</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td name="columnThreeData>
         <select>
            <option value="1">Data1</option>
            <option value="2">Data2</option>
            <option value="3">Data3</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button id="saveBtn"></button>
```

I have a function set up to add the class "changedRow" to any tr that was changed. By using that, I am able to get only the changed rows but it seems I can get the selected values only (but I am missing columnOneData) or I can get all values (but that includes all options, not just chosen option) but have not been able to narrow it down to what I need. In the end I need to send the columnOneData & the selected values for columnTwoData & columnThreeData back to my php code to update the database. *(Example as if user had made selections to both rows)*

```
 "columnOneData":123456, "columnTwoData":1, "columnThreeData":2
 "columnOneData":987654, "columnTwoData":2, "columnThreeData":3
```

Any suggestions for the best way to approach this would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to provide your js code that is not working, so it is easier for others to answer you as they can modify on your code.

Regardless, try the following code:

```
var all_data = [];
$('#myTable tr.changedRow').each(function() {
    all_data.push({
        columnOneData: $(this).find('td[name="columnOneData"]').text(),
        columnTwoData: $(this).find('td[name="columnTwoData"] select').val(),
        columnThreeData: $(this).find('td[name="columnThreeData"] select').val()
    });
});
```

[Working sample in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malcolmkee/ksdfvqt6/)

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you've got some quotes missing for your name and ID attributes.

```
<table id="myTable>
...
<td name="columnThreeData>
```

...should be...

```
<table id="myTable">
...
<td name="columnThreeData">
```

(I would use class or ID instead of name.)

As for getting the values, I'm not 100% sure what the problem is that you're having but here's my first stab at doing what I think you're asking to do:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3nm0wvq/